# Can a social security card be used/required as identification?

Tags: united-states, sec, fiduciary-duties, social-security

A FINRA-regulated institution is restricting my account on suspicion of identity theft and requiring that I give them a copy of my social security *card* which I of course don't have because what use does it even have? It has no photo or even date of birth or other identifying details so why would anyone even keep it?

Even the SSA itself suggests that it is useless and unimportant, that if you've lost it you probably don't even need to replace it. Furthermore you can even be prohibited from obtaining a replacement if you get too many in a year or your lifetime. What if you're past your quota?

In short, is it legal to require one to present their SSC as a precondition to accessing one's own funds? And corollary, are there any SEC/FINRA regulations that *require* an institution to demand one's SSC as identification?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Private companies asking for Social Security Number?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33991/private-companies-asking-for-social-security-number)

Comment: Clearly it does *not* answer or even ask the same question.

Comment: Yes @user6726, I agree. Thank you

Comment: The linked question is about use under HIPPA, and indeed specifically mentions use of a SSC benign forbidden by that act. This is about use by a financial institution under a quite different law. Not a dupe.

Comment: And not only that, but the question linked is actually about the social security *number*, not the *card* itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unquestionable common law property right to what is in these accounts. An institution can make reasonable demands that you prove that you are the person entitled to that account. No aspect of [Title 17](https://www.ecfr.gov/search?search%5Bdate%5D=current&search%5Bhierarchy%5D%5Btitle%5D=17&search%5Bquery%5D=social%20security%20card&view=standard) (SEC) requires the presentation of an SS card, nor does any part of Title 17 authorize an institution to deny a person's property rights because they do not present an SS card. The institution can make reasonable requirements for proof of identity, and [26 USC 6109](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6109) says what that means w.r.t. identifying numbers. Nothing therein say anything about a *card* w.r.t. connecting a person to a TIN. This can involve the institution submitting forms, see [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1103982/000119312509247360/dex995.htm). It is most likely that they have to submit form W-9 – I assume you have an SS number. That is the extent to which the brokerage company can legally delay you accessing your property.

Comment: Yes, I have a social security number which they required when I opened my account. Would it be legal for them to close my account in retaliation for my citing both the above mentioned statutes and my common law right to that property? This is a company that deceptively told me to hold while they "checked into my account" after I spoke for several minutes after informing them that I too was recording the call and would publish it online to show the world what the were doing if they weren't reasonable. After that she returned and just said that due to the call being recorded by me they would no

Comment: Longer be able to communicate with me by phone so they'd email me the information. Clearly they are allergic to anything that smells of accountability.

Comment: They are not obligated to speak to you by phone, or by email, so at this point you may have to lawyer up. Demands by certified mail are always a good idea, and threatening to record and disseminate is always a bad idea. There is nothing statutory that prevents them from "closing your account", but they are not authorized to seize or liquidate your holdings (as I say, lawyer time). Your agreement with the firm may address the question of whether they are contractually enabled to close the account.

Comment: All excellent advice, but a couple of questions: on what basis do you say that threatening to record and disseminate is a bad idea?

Comment: And further, out of fascination, can you explain a bit more about what is meant as such by the statement that I have a common law property right to what's in those accounts? What actually is the basis of that right, and more specifically, what does it mean to qualify it as a *common law* right? Does it make the right somehow more fundamental/absolute/transcendental to other issues?

Comment: "Bad idea" in the sense that it could cause the company to be less cooperative, as you observed. Under common law (e.g. US law, not European law) certain rights are "traditional" and arise from hundreds of years of court cases, as opposed to being spelled out by specific pieces of statutes. This is especially relevant for concepts of contract and property – you don't have to rely on a federal statute that says what it means to "own" shares of stock.

Comment: That is quite puzzling, though. Shouldn't it logically provoke them to be more accountable and reasonable, and therefore cooperative?

Comment: Yes, I know what common law is, and understand the idea of common law torts for example, but typically don't these doctrines established by common law have names and also particular case precedents? Property rights almost seem more fundamental/axiomatic than common law torts because they would seem to have existed for time immemorial, certainly to have preceded common law, and are indeed the axiomatic basis for many common law torts such as for example trover or possibly trespass.

Comment: But are there generally any more particular citations for common law doctrines than just simply "common law," as a statutory provision can be traced to a particular line or paragraph of an accordingly particular statute in a given year? Why are certain common law concepts cited as simply "common law X/Y/Z" rather than by the particular precedent case decision, while other precedent concepts are cited by the actual case that established them, and are there differences between such two categories of common law concepts?

Comment: @Joseph P. While there is a common-law right to withdraw bank deposits, the more relevant law is I think the Uniform commercial code [Article 4](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/4) and Feder Reserver Regulation CC, available  in [12 CFR 229](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-12/chapter-II/subchapter-A/part-229/subpart-B) subpart B

Comment: Wow, American legislation is so much more convoluted and difficult to read than British legislation.

Comment: @JosephP. the legislation is pretty trivial. The difficulty arises from the power of the executive branch to create second order interpretations of legislation i.e. "regulations".

Comment: Are you talking about in these particular cases or about American legislation in general? I'm just talking about what's directly in those links above from David.

Answer (score 2):

Many financial institutions have to withhold taxes on the customer's behalf or at least notify the federal government of transactions like interest payments. To do that they need the customer's SSN or tax payer id and [they are authorized to require that information](https://www.helpwithmybank.gov/help-topics/bank-accounts/required-identification/id-ssn.html). It isn't so much for ID purposes as making sure the info gets to the right tax account. If they suspect you of identity theft they may need some sort of documentary evidence of your SSN or taxpayer id rather than just your say so

As trivial as it seems, [a social security card is legal proof of your SSN](https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10559.pdf)

Comment: However, there is no law / regulation that *requires* presentation of an SS card to satisfy the requirement to supply an SS number. So the question is whether an institution can deprive you of access to your property if you don't supply a particular document, which is not *required* by law. It is unlikely that they could deprive a person of their property over a questionable contractual technicality.

Comment: From the advice by the SSA: "A Social Security card is legal proof of an SSN. In most cases, the actual card is not necessary but,
if your agency or organization requires proof, and
the person can’t produce a card, there are other documents that show their SSN. If other documents are not available, that person will need a replacement card."

Comment: It's not stated in the original question whether other documents are available. It's also worth noting a question of possible identity theft has been raised, so technicalities are going to be important.

Comment: Please, please, you two gentlemen duke (or hash) this one out as fully as you're able! This is causing massive problems for me and I need to know what options are available because many courses of action might not be feasible when I pursue them and I won't necessarily know for weeks or months. For the record, I have much other proof of identity, like birth cert and others. Just not SSC. Yes, I believe the institution will claim that technicalities are very important. Also, to clarify, I have many other documents that might be much harder to forge than a lousy/flimsy social security card.

Comment: @JosephP. Is there a reason that obtaining a replacement card is particularly onerous? I've done it before for myself and for one of my kids and it wasn't that big of a deal.

Comment: @ohwilleke yes, potentially several (or it may prove not to be at all) but all that I'd rather not discuss.

Comment: @JosephP I think you need to at least entertain the notion that they are NOT asking for you SS Card as ID, but rather as proof of your SSN, which is a slightly different thing. Consider the position of the financial institution which is legally responsible for reporting your transactions to the IRS. To do that they need your SSN or tpid. According to your question something has happened to make them worry about identity theft. Maybe somebody else has been using your SSN and the IRS has flagged them about it. They need to get some document from you legally establishing that it is YOUR SSN.

Comment: That is, the financial institute may already be perfectly convinced that you are the Joseph P. that lives on Primrose Lane, but they need legal proof that the Joseph P. who lives on Primrose Lane's SSN is XXX-XX-XXXX. Weirdly the little cardboard card from the SSA provides that, even though it is laughably easy to fake.

Comment: They have already told me that the account was flagged simply because of me changing to a different browser, which was detected as "logging in from multiple devices."

Comment: But once it is flagged and restricted it cannot be unrestricted without one's SSC.

Comment: However, while I strongly agree with the possibility which you propose, the staff with whom I've spoken have all justified the requirement by explaining to me "what if you weren't you"? "We are doing to verify your identity" "to keep you safe". (not to keep you honest with respect to your SSN). However they have required it at the same time as and together with other documents that are identification documents. So it could be a procedure designed to (inconsiderately and unnecessarily onerously to the customer) simultaneously verify their identity and SSN all in one go in scenarios where

Comment: Anything fishy is detected on the account.

Answer (score 1):

No.  My social security card said on its face: **Not to be used for identification.**

I note, however, that I haven't seen my card for decades.  I think more recent cards lack that note.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you